# buscador php html mysql

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Necesito por favor arreglar este buscador para que me funcione, el código lo encontré y me parece interesante por la forma como según funciona, pero al ponerlo no hace nada, solo me muestra el código nuevamente en el navegador, según me dicen debo poner las variables *post* que recojan información, pero no se de **php** para poder arreglarlo, entiendo el concepto que debo crear una variable que recoja la informacion del formulario pero no se como adaptarlo, quisiera por favor entender el codigo y me ayuden a que funcione, la base se llama **academ**, la tabla *login* y los campos de momento *user, email*, deberia reconocer la palabra a buscar en **html** un *input* y mostrarme los campos de la busqueda en **html**.

Adjunto lo que tengo.

[image: imagen de la pag]

```
<!--debe ser en paginas independientes el html y php--->
<tr>            
        <form method="post" action="../../Adminback/buscar.php" >
            <td align="center">
                <input type="text" name="busqueda" value="" />
            </td>
        </tr>

<?php
//cadena de conexion
mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
// DEBO PREPARAR LOS TEXTOS QUE VOY A BUSCAR si la cadena existe
if ($busqueda<>''){
  //CUENTA EL NUMERO DE PALABRAS
  $trozos=explode(" ",$busqueda);
  $numero=count($trozos);
  if ($numero==1) {
    //SI SOLO HAY UNA PALABRA DE BUSQUEDA SE ESTABLECE UNA INSTRUCION CON LIKE
    $cadbusca="SELECT  REFERENCIA, user FROM academ WHERE VISIBLE =1
      AND email LIKE  '%$busqueda%' OR user LIKE  '%$busqueda%' LIMIT 50";
  } elseif ($numero>1) {
    //SI HAY UNA FRASE SE UTILIZA EL ALGORTIMO DE BUSQUEDA AVANZADO DE MATCH AGAINST
    //busqueda de frases con mas de una palabra y un algoritmo especializado
    $cadbusca="SELECT  REFERENCIA, user, MATCH ( user, email )
      AGAINST (  '$busqueda' ) AS Score FROM academ WHERE
      MATCH ( user, email ) AGAINST (  '$busqueda' ) ORDER  BY Score DESC LIMIT 50";
  }
  $result=mysqli("academ", $cadbusca);
  While($row=mysqli_fetch_object($result))
  {
    //Mostramos los titulos de los articulos o lo que deseemos...
    $referencia=$row->REFERENCIA;
    $titulo=$row->TITULO;
    echo $referencia." - ".$titulo."<br>";
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Cómo estás ejecutando el script, en servidor web o en tu computadora?

Comment: Hola, en una computadora, con wamp server, debo estar metiendo mal los parametros de busqueda y no esta apuntando al html dond quiero mostrarlo, no se como hacerlo

Comment: El primer problema que tienes es que mysqli_connect() devuelve el recurso de conexión a base de datos, que necesitarás para ejecutar cualquier consulta, y no lo estás asignando a una variable.

Comment: Entiendo el contexto delo que me dices, pero no se como se hace. me podrías ayudara corregir el código, he intentado pero no me sale, si eres tan  amble d enseñarme como se pondría esa variable para guardar el resultado y usarlo, he buscado pero siempre lo hacen con php dentro de la misma pagina de html y yoquiero que funcione independiente el php como deberia ser del html, tengo la idea no se plasmarla, conclusion quiero q me busque lo q entra al input y se guarda en la base, q se muestre en <table> sin poner codigo php alli atraves d la llamda al dato en la pag php, guiame porfa